# Uploading profile image and proceeding to next

Tags: java, android

I have two activities. SetupActivity.java and ProfileImageActivity.java.

SetupActivity.java

```
   public class SetupActivity extends AppCompatActivity
{
    @BindView(R.id.setup_name) EditText _nameText;
    @BindView(R.id.setup_username) EditText _userNameText;
    @BindView(R.id.setup_blood_group) EditText _bloodGroupText;
    @BindView(R.id.setup_mobile) EditText _mobileText;
    @BindView(R.id.save_profile_button) Button _saveProfileButton;
    //private CircleImageView ProfileImage;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;

    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;
    String currentUserID;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_setup);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);

        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        currentUserID = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);


        _saveProfileButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SaveAccountSetupInformation();
            }

        });
    }
    private void SaveAccountSetupInformation()
    {
        String fullname=_nameText.getText().toString();
        String username = _userNameText.getText().toString();
        String mobilenumber = _mobileText.getText().toString();
        String bloodgroup = _bloodGroupText.getText().toString();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(username))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please write your username...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mobilenumber))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please give your mobile number...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(bloodgroup))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please give your exact blood group...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(fullname))
        {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Please give your fullname..", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        else
        {
            loadingBar.setTitle("Saving Information");
            loadingBar.setMessage("Please wait, while we are creating your new Account...");
            loadingBar.show();
            loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

            HashMap userMap = new HashMap();
            userMap.put("username", username);
            userMap.put("fullname",fullname);
            userMap.put("mobilenumber", mobilenumber);
            userMap.put("bloodgroup", bloodgroup);
            userMap.put("status", "Hey there, i am using Kaarai Siragugal Android App.");
            userMap.put("gender", "none");
            userMap.put("dob", "none");
            userMap.put("relationshipstatus", "none");
            UsersRef.updateChildren(userMap).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task task)
                {
                    if(task.isSuccessful())
                    {
                        SendUserToProfileImageActivity();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "your Account is created Successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        String message =  task.getException().getMessage();
                        Toast.makeText(SetupActivity.this, "Error Occured: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }



    private void SendUserToProfileImageActivity()
    {
        Intent mainIntent = new Intent(SetupActivity.this, ProfileImageActivity.class);
        mainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
        startActivity(mainIntent);
        finish();
    }
}
```

ProfileImageActivity.java

```
    public class ProfileImageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private CircleImageView ProfileImage;
    private FirebaseAuth mAuth;
    private ProgressDialog loadingBar;
    private StorageReference UserProfileImageRef;
    String currentUserID;
    final static int Gallery_Pick = 1;
    @BindView(R.id.save_profile_image_button)
    Button _saveProfileImageButton;
    private DatabaseReference UsersRef;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_profile_image);
        ButterKnife.bind(this);
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        ProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_profile_image);
        UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
        currentUserID = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
        UserProfileImageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference().child("Profile Images");
        ProfileImage = (CircleImageView) findViewById(R.id.save_profile_image);
        loadingBar = new ProgressDialog(this);
        _saveProfileImageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SaveProfileImage();
            }
        });
        ProfileImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent galleryIntent = new Intent();
                galleryIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
                galleryIntent.setType("image/*");
                startActivityForResult(galleryIntent, Gallery_Pick);
            }
        });

    }





    private void SaveProfileImage() {
        UsersRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()) {
                    if (dataSnapshot.hasChild("profileimage")) {
                        String image = dataSnapshot.child("profileimage").getValue().toString();
                        Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(ProfileImage);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(ProfileImageActivity.this, "Please select profile image first.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == Gallery_Pick && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
            Uri imageUri = data.getData();

            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .setAspectRatio(1, 1)
                    .start(this);
        }

        // Cuando se pulsa en el crop button
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);

            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

                loadingBar.setTitle("Profile Image");
                loadingBar.setMessage("Wait while we save your image...");
                loadingBar.show();
                loadingBar.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);

                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();

                StorageReference filePath = UserProfileImageRef.child(currentUserID + ".jpg");

                filePath.putFile(resultUri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {

                            Toast.makeText(ProfileImageActivity.this, "Your image has been saved...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                            Task<Uri> result = task.getResult().getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl();

                            result.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onSuccess(Uri uri) {
                                    final String downloadUrl = uri.toString();

                                    UsersRef.child("profileimage").setValue(downloadUrl)
                                            .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                                @Override
                                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                                        Intent selfIntent = new Intent(ProfileImageActivity.this, ProfileImageActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(selfIntent);

                                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileImageActivity.this, "Your Image looks beautiful...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                        Intent MainIntent=new Intent(ProfileImageActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                                                        startActivity(MainIntent);
                                                        MainIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                                                        finish();
                                                    } else {
                                                        String message = task.getException().getMessage();
                                                        Toast.makeText(ProfileImageActivity.this, "Error: " + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                                        loadingBar.dismiss();
                                                    }
                                                }
                                            });
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    }
                });
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(ProfileImageActivity.this, "Error: \n" + "The image has not been cropped well. Try again.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                loadingBar.dismiss();
            }
        }
    }
    }
```

The SetupActivity.java gets user information such as name username bloodgroup and mobile number and saves it to Firebase Database. It runs well. 
The ProfileImageActivity.java should get the cropped profile image of the user and have to save it to the database of the user. For cropping, I used a repository from github. After the setupActivity, the app crahses saying

```
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Can't pass null for argument 'pathString' in child()
    at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@16.0.5:101)
    at blackevil.com.kaaraisiragugal.ProfileImageActivity.onCreate(ProfileImageActivity.java:52)
```

And also the app exits but the info given in SetupActivity are saved correctly into the database. And also i need to stop the user going to next activity from ProfileImageActivity without selecting a profile image.

Comment: can you please point out your Line ProfileImageActivity.java:52?

Comment: UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);

Comment: First verify that do FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference() contains a child with name "Users". Seems you are trying to fetch the data from a wrong level of data binded to that object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, you have

```
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
currentUserID = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
```

Where in `.child(currentUserID)` currentUserID is null cause you are getting the currentUserID in the second line.

> seriously!?

It should be like below:

```
currentUserID = mAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
UsersRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users").child(currentUserID);
```

Comment: Worked like a charm man!!!!!! <3 <3 <3. Now i want to restrict user not to go to nextactivity after ProfileImageActivity without selecting a ProfileImage. How to do that?

Comment: How to restrict user not to go to next activity without image?

Comment: create a flag `private boolean imageUploaded = false;` In your `if (task.isSuccessful())` set the `imageUploaded = true;` Finally, before going to next activity if the `imageUploaded` is true. If not, don't `startActivity(nextIntent)`

Answer (score 0):

Try to make check you string path is null or not. and make condition first then after show into Picasso.

```
 if (image!=null && !TextUtils.isEmpty(image))
 Picasso.get().load(image).placeholder(R.drawable.profile).into(ProfileImage);
```

Comment: The ProfileImageActivity is not appearing at all. After the SetupActivity, the app crashes.

Comment: refer first this link https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-realtime-database-crud/